# Install Sitecore 9.0 update 2 encountered warnings

Tags: habitat

I'm trying to install Habitat on my machine, according to this instruction [01-Getting-Started](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started). However when I look back the script log, I got as bellow message

[image]

Should we skip these warning messages or we need to update somethings before running install.ps1 script?

Finally the site is still working well http://habitat.dev.local/

Please advise, 
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is the first time you are installing then those warnings are fine to ignore. Those warnings are stating that those services could not be stopped/found because they wouldn't exist yet.

If you already had the site installed, the install script would stop the services so that new files could be installed over the top of them.

You can safely ignore those warnings.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Seal for your explanation 

However this is not my first installation, This is 3rd after installing sc8, sc9 and sc902

Best 
Quách

Comment: right, but did all those installations have the same name? The services and sites are unique to each instance.